# I get CORS error in SharePoint. I also changed web-config but nothing happens

Tags: rest, web-services, ajax, cors

I call AJAX request and the browser got CORS error. I tried to add `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` in IIS web.config. But it doesn't work. I have two servers. My AJAX is true only when I have this issue. So, how can I resolve it?

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

Comment: Is this 2016 or 2019? It overrides CORS setting in code is the reason I ask.

Comment: which endpoint you are trying to reach?
please provide us with some code.

Comment: I want to reach other asmx url. And we use Sharepoint 2016. I added the codes i write above in web.config. I added the same to ajax in frontend. But Nothing's changed . Also, i try Url Rewrite. I made rules in there. And this doesn't work for me.